# how to setup a globally used broadcastreceiver that manipulates views in android

Tags: android

I have a custom title bar used in every activity in my app. I have a broadcast receiver that I want manipulating said title bar,

I have this in my custom application class,

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {

        public static final String ACTION_RESPONSE = "org.company.com.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";                                                                                

        private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                MyApplication.log("received");
                //hide the visible progress dialog spinner in title bar

            }
        }; 

        public BroadcastReceiver getBroadcastReceiver() {
            return receiver;
        }   
    }
```

I have this in every one of my Activities' onCreate,

```
MyApplication application = ((MyApplication) getApplication());
registerReceiver(application.getBroadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter(MyApplication.ACTION_RESPONSE));
```

What I am trying to do is to find a nice OOP way to do this. I realize that in every activity I can bind a broadcastreceiver that manipulates the view as long as the braodcastreceiver is declared in the activity, but copy pasting that same code 15+ times doesn't make sense to me. Then the next issue is that inside of the MyApplication class, I don't have access to any of the views. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Why not make a custom activity class instead and derive all of your activities from that class?  You can store the current state of things in the application class and tie it together with your custom activity.

Comment: "I have a broadcast receiver that I want manipulating said title bar" -- why? What problem do you think you are trying to solve this way?

Comment: @CommonsWare i have an IntentService uploading a big file. i want to turn off the progress dialog when that file is done. i am new to android and am open to more correct solutions

Comment: @dagalpin how do i make one custom activity class when i am using multiple activities (ListActivity and Activity) ?

Comment: Don't use a `ProgressDialog` in the first place. If you are using an `IntentService`, you are specifically assuming that the upload should continue even if the user exits your UI. Use `Notifications` to let the user know about progress and completion of such a background operation.